# В списке есть значения но Питон все равно ругается "pop from empty list". Что не так?

Tags: python, циклы, список, while

```py
sandwich_orders = ['hamburger', 'panini', 'BLT', 'Monte-Kristo']
finished_sandwiches = []
for sandwich in sandwich_orders:
    print(f"I made you {sandwich}")
while True:
    order = sandwich_orders.pop()
    finished_sandwiches.append(order)
    print(finished_sandwiches)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
while True: # <-- нет проверки на исчерпание списка
    order = sandwich_orders.pop()
    ...
```

Нужно поменять условие цикла, чтобы он прекратился, когда вы исчерпаете список. Сейчас вы продолжаете извлекать элементы с помощью `.pop` даже из пустого списка.

```py
while sandwich_orders:
    order = sandwich_orders.pop()
    ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!)

Answer (score 2):

```
sandwich_orders = ['hamburger', 'panini', 'BLT', 'Monte-Kristo']
finished_sandwiches = []
for sandwich in sandwich_orders:
    print(f"I made you {sandwich}")
while len(sandwich_orders) > 0:
    order = sandwich_orders.pop()
    finished_sandwiches.append(order)
    print(finished_sandwiches)
```

Поменяйте условие в цикле while

Answer (score 1):

Все достаточно просто, если знать, что тип `list` изменяемый. Следовательно, вызывая, метод `pop()` в бесконечном цикле, вы в конце концов получите пустой список. Вопрос, а что вы ожидаете? У вас нет выхода из цикла `while`, при пустом списку `sandwich_orders`

Добавьте в конец проверку длины списка, и у вас ошибка пропадет

```py
while True:
    order = sandwich_orders.pop()
    finished_sandwiches.append(order)
    print(finished_sandwiches)
    if len(sandwich_orders) == 0:
        break
```